# Representation in memory for one pixel of image data

Tags: c++, graphics

I can't get me mind to understand how a standard TGA 32bit image is arranged in memory after being loaded from file. I do however understand the idea of bytes per pixel, but i don't understand how the color components (RGBA) are layed out in memory for the one pixel. In other words, how the bytes for one pixel are arranged inside the array.

Will someone please give me some insight on how the RGBA information is stored in memory for one pixal of image data, is all the information for one pixel within the bytes per pixel range?

Also i am loading my image with these options:

`ifstream reader_;`

...

`reader_.open(path.c_str(), ios_base::in | ios::binary);`

...

`reader_.read((char*)(&_image.data[0]), size);`

Comment: R then G then B then A

Comment: Thx for the replay. ^^ How do i access just the A (alpha) part only for one pixel if all three (R then G then B then A) are combined?

Comment: @8-bitButterfly that's in my answer

Comment: That's arbitrary. There's no "standard" way to store image data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way, which in my opinion is better than extracting data, is using a cast.
Using operators and bit arithmetic has its cost, making the compiler cast to the right format is free.

```
struct RGBA
{
   uint8t r;
   uint8t g;
   uint8t b;
   uint8t a;
}

char* myBitmap = GetBitMapPointer();
RGBA* rgbaPointer = reinterpert_cast<RGBA*>(myBitmap);

//use pointer arithmetic from now on....
uint8t myFirstAvalue = rgbaPointer->a;

//second pixel
rgbaPointer++;
uint8t mySecondAvalue = rgbaPointer->a;
```

Comment: Eh, a combination of the 5.2.10 in the standard, and 3.9 of course states: `The object representation of an object of type T is the sequence of N unsigned char objects taken up by
the object of type T, where N equals sizeof(T). The value representation of an object is the set of bits that
hold the value of type T. For trivially copyable types, the value representation is a set of bits in the object
representation that determines a value, which is one discrete element of an implementation-defined set of
values.`

Comment: @Yochai Timmer I really like the answer you presented. This is almost exactly what i needed for extracting alpha information per pixel. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 3):

In memory everything becomes a "bitmap". It depends on the pixel format you use. In general, RGB or RGBA (being 8 bits/1 byte per channel) is the most common, but you can have other pixel formats, example:

- bitmaps with less than 32-bit color, example: for 8-bit, where you have only 256 possible colors per pixel.
- bitmaps with different bits per channel, example 16 bits "per channel", so you have more precision on your color information.
- formats with different order of channels: formats like ARGB, ABGR, BGR
- monochromatic (1 bit per pixel)... so in this case, 1 byte can have up to 8 pixels!

You can even "invent" one pixel format if you want...

Answer (score 2):

If you treat your buffer as being of type `uint32t *` then each pixel will occupy one element of the buffer.

The precise arrangement of RGBA values within each `uint32t` will depend on the file format.  You *might* find `R` in the lowest byte, and `A` in the highest byte:

```
uint8t r = (*p >>  0) & 0xff;       // cast as required
uint8t g = (*p >>  8) & 0xff;     
uint8t b = (*p >> 16) & 0xff;    
uint8t a = (*p >> 24) & 0xff;
```

Or, you might not ;-).  Which order the fields are packed also depends on the "endianess" of the machine running the code - this above would be for little-endian (e.g. Intel) architectures.

Comment: CPU architecture has nothing to do with image data, until you're using SIMD instructions on the pixels.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz sure it does, when you read it.  Because it's read via a multibyte `uint32t` variable, on a big-endian architecture the code above would put the 3rd byte in `R` instead of the 0th byte.

Comment: I particularly meant the "would put". It's not backed by anything. Actually, GPUs routinely store informations in BGRA *internal* format, which is still present to the user as RGBA format.